# HTML follow on line indent alignment

Tags: html, text-alignment

I'm adding content to a predefined layout that I cannot modify but allows any HTML. I wish to align a piece of text like a floating text box but due to the h4 and p classes that I can't change it is proving difficult.

What I'd like to see is: [image: this alignment]

But it currently looks like: [image: this]

The resulting HTML is currently:

```
<div class="element property-line"><h4 class="property-name">Foo</h4>
<p class="p property-text">
    BAR <div style="line-height: 90%;";>
    <i> quite a long but of text that needs to wrap</i></div>
<p></p></div>
```

...where my content starts at *BAR* and ends with the *i* and *div* end tags.

I think I may be missing a formatting trick.

Comment: Why are you using this `<div style="line-height: 90%;";>` ?

Comment: There is a lot of text that needs to fit in to a small space, @hamza. I cannot reduce the font size any further but I can squish it on by reducing the line-height ever so slightly.

Comment: I've tried to edit my question to avoid more down votes but it would be helpful to understand why it already has two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used MS Word to create a document as I wanted it to appear and then tripped out all the extraneous twaddle it puts in; leaving me with:

```
<p style="margin-left:50pt; text-indent:-50pt">
```

then found a workaround to mimic the `<h4 class=` and `<p class=` sections so that it all fit into one `<div>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="element property-line">
    <h4 class="property-name">Foo</h4>
    <p class="p property-text">
        BAR 
        <span style="line-height: 90%;">
             <i> quite a long but of text that needs to wrap</i>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

That should be more what you're after, `<span>` tags are suited for changing/styling text within paragraphs because `<div>` tags are more for structural elements.

Your original code also had an extra opening `<p>` on the last line.

Comment: `span` does indeed keep the line-height and continues the text on the first line, @EbeenAndGone. I just need to right justify the spanned text somehow.  The additional `<p>` is part of a Javascript construct so I can't remove it.

Comment: Try: `<span style-"line-height: 90%; text-align:justify;">`

Also see: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-justify.asp

Comment: Thanks, @EbeenAndGone, but I found a workaround for the issue I was having and I'm considering deleting this question to avoid the -2 rep.

Comment: That very much goes against the spirit of stackoverflow. Others might find this thread useful. Regardless of you finding a solution to your original issue, don't delete the question. It might be helpful to others if you explain what your solution was in the end.